# Using Switch for android 2.3

Tags: android, custom-controls

I am creating a small android app and I need a switch button in my app, and I want this app to work on android 2.3 devices too. But switches are not available in 2.3.
Is there any implementation that can be done for implementing Switch by a custom control?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. This is pretty easy to resolve. Rather than using a `Switch` simply use a `CheckBox`. You then customise the checkbox to look like a switch by creating 3 seperate XML files:

- One to define what the `CheckBox` looks like when it is "unchecked".
- One to define what the `CheckBox` looks like when it is "checked".
- One to define the selector for your `Checkbox`.

You can check out [this tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/create-a-custom-checkbox-in-your-android-app/1257) for more info :)